# What is the number of edges in a 2-regular graph that has 7 vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

I've just started learning about graph theory and I am doing some exercises online.

This is the question I'm currently on:

What is the number of edges in a 2-regular graph that has 7 vertices?

And

What is the smallest number of edges in a connected graph with 6 vertices?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: The nice thing about graph theory is that it is accessible.  A preschool child can answer both of those questions with a pencil and a piece of scrap paper once they understand the vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, remember your hand-shaking lemma:

$$\sum\limits_{v\in V}\deg(v) = 2|E|$$

Next, remember that it means to be $2$-regular and notice that the problem tells you there are seven vertices.

> The graph being $2$-regular means that $\deg(v)=2$ for all $v\in V$, so the above simplifies as $7\cdot 2 = 2|E|$, and so $|E|=7$

---

For the second, recall that any connected graph has a subgraph which is a spanning tree and that trees are the graphs with the smallest number of edges such that the graph remains connected.

How many edges are there in a tree over six vertices?

> A tree on $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, so there are at least $5$ edges for a connected graph on six vertices.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Admittedly this is all new to me, could you give me the answers so I can work backwards to understand it? Need to read up on graph theory more too. Thanks!

Comment: @tyrionweiss44 I *did* give you the answers... and an explanation for the answers.

Comment: Sorry JM, didnt notice the see spoiler section. On the plus side I manage to work it out myself. Many thanks for your time and patience!